# Supported file types with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

In what format can a drawn polyline (in a custom-built software) be saved so as to be able to be converted to shapefiles or usable in ArcGIS?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why can't you just save to a shapefile format in the first place? Its a mostly-open format.

Comment: Omololu can you please explain your question further - it is currently unclear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

For Vector format there are many formats supported.
This [10.0 help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html?TopicName=Data_formats_supported_in_ArcGIS#/A_quick_tour_of_data_management/00r90000009m000000/) has links to each, the other storage options seems to be where you are asking your question.

This [9.3 help page](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Data_formats_supported_in_ArcGIS) is a little dated.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would try incorporate a library/API to write the data out of my software. FME Objects for a commercial solution, OGR for an open source one. Either one would be able to write directly to Shape.

If you really want to write a data format "manually" then go for a simple ASCII one like an x/y CSV format, WKT, some flavour of GML, or maybe even GeoJSON (Esri JSON?) - they'd be relatively simple and have tools available to convert them.